# how to save data form input to json file with javascript?

Tags: html, json

This is my code but doesn't work. How do I save data form inputs to json file and send to server?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Registration</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="myform" action="register.json">
    <label>Vesete ime</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" value="name">
    <label>Vnesete password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" value="password">
    <button id="btn" type="submit" value="submit">Potvrdi</button>
</form>
```

This is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var x ={ "name":" ", "password":" "};
        var myJSON = JSON.stringify(x);
        document.getElementsByTagName("input").innerHTML = myJSON; 
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'register', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.onload = function () {

        console.log(this.responseText);
    };
    xhr.send('name=name&password=password');
    </script>
```

in the browser show this file:///var/www/html/register.json?name=marina&password=1234567 but not save in json file. Plese help me in the first tame work with json.

Comment: you can't directly write to a json file. You need to use something as a back end, such as **nodejs**.

Comment: Which server are you running? Apache?

Comment: Yes. Apache but i sloved problem wuth server. But dont know how to save data form to json file with nodejs? Thank y

Answer (score 0):

To save data to the server you need to:

1. Use a server! Your URL starts with `file:` which shows you are accessing a local file and not making an HTTP request to a server.
2. Write server-side code that will read the data you are sending and save it. Just making a request to a static file won't change anything (otherwise anyone could change any page on any website!). How you do this will depend on which server you use and which server-side programming language you pick. Use a search engine to find an introductory tutorial for server-side programming using the language of your choice. (e.g. for [Perl](http://perldancer.org/quickstart), [JavaScript](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/installing.html), or [Python](https://www.djangoproject.com/start/)).